# Use Indexed View to limit number of duplicates in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that may contain duplicates.  I would like to constrain the table to allow only a certain number of duplicates (e.g. 100).  I know that this can be achieved using a UDF and a table constraint - but I would like to avoid that as there are disadvantages including performance.

Instead, I am trying the approach of using a unique constraint on an indexed view.  Here is what I have tried:

```
CREATE VIEW DuplicateCheckView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT        1 AS Marker
    UNION ALL
    SELECT        1 AS Marker
    FROM          DuplicateContainingTable
    GROUP BY      KeyColumn1, KeyColumn2, KeyColumn3 
    HAVING        COUNT(1) > 100 
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IXU_DuplicatesCheck
   ON DuplicateCheckView (Marker);
GO
```

This results in the error

```
Msg 10116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create index on view 'DuplicatesCheckView' because it contains one or more UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT operators. Consider creating a separate indexed view for each query that is an input to the UNION, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT operators of the original view.
```

OK I understand the error (but not really why it has to be that way), is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Let's presume indexed view for this case is a good idea. What for do you need that union?

Comment: When you are explicitly using the value `1` for every row of the result for your `marker` column, how do you expect them to be `unique`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I do not want any instances of more than 100 duplicates.  Without the UNION, If I have just one instance then then the index will be still hold unique.  The purpose of the UNION is so that the first instance of excessive duplicates will result in error.

Comment: @Raj pls see comment above

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, additional element issue can be fixed by replacing of strict `>100` with `>=100`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin the GROUP BY / HAVING only applies to the second part of the union so no thay doesn't help.  Thanks for commenting.  I have given up on this approach as I don't think it's possible, I wrote a trigger-based check instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Another barrier is that HAVING clause is not allowed in indexed view either (as well as sub-queries).  I have instead implemented a trigger-based approach.